# External merge-sort, but for dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following case:

Very large file of lines of of integers of random length each, i.e.,

**input.dat**

```
1 3 5 6
3 5 7
2 3 7 8
```

I need to bring this file to the following form represented by a dictionary:

**final dict**

```
{    
    1: [1],
    2: [3],
    3: [1, 2, 3],
    5: [1, 2],
    6: [1],
    7: [2, 3],
    8: [3]
}
```

So every new number that I encounter is a key on my dictionary, and as value it will have a list of all the lines it was found in the input file. But since the input file is too large to fit in memory, while reading it line by line I update the dictionary until it reaches let's say *1MB*, and once it does I save it to a temporary file, and start again.

So in the fictional case where I could only fit one line of the input file in memory I would have:

**partial dict 1**

```
{    
    1: [1],
    3: [1],
    5: [1],
    6: [1]
}
```

**partial dict 2**

```
{    
    3: [2],
    5: [2],
    7: [2]
}
```

**partial dict 3**

```
{   
    2: [3],
    3: [3],
    7: [3],
    8: [3]
}
```

By the end of it I'm left with a number of temporary files holding each partial dictionary that I need to merge in order to create a large file containing "**final dict**" again. I am assuming here that one key, value pair of **final dict** will always fit in memory and for each such key, value pair, on each file, I scan all the other files and if I find it I sort and merge their values. Once I checked all the files I store it in the final output file.

Working iteratively like this for every file is a bit slow. Is there a better algorithm to merge these files faster?

Comment: So **input.dat** is your actual input and the actual desired output is a file you haven't shown yet?

Comment: How many lines and numbers are in the input file?

Comment: Have you tried not writing the temporary files?

Comment: @sahasrara62 then I would have to do much more frequent reads and writes for a key that I could encounter millions of times. It's an interesting idea though, I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @snaikar this adds the complexity of having to sort the dictionaries but it sounds interesting. I will think/try it, and see how it goes.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but I have to ask: Why are you sorting anything here? The lists in `final dict` should start off sorted and by inserting in order they'll stay sorted. There's no need to sort each intermediate list because you must examine each value in the intermediate list regardless of what else you do.

Comment: @MichaelRuth yes you are correct, the intermediate dictionaries require no sorting. But I had that step there just to be sure. I guess I can assume I will always read the temporary files with the order they were originally created.

Comment: Are you ever going to clarify the task? I still don't know what the desired output is. You say it doesn't fit into memory, but the only "result" you've shown is a dict, and a dict is in memory. I still don't know how the desired output file looks like that is mysteriously "represented" by that dict.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have many keys representing an ID of some sort, where each key is associated with a list of integers (so a dictionary). I explain how I come up with these dictionaries in detail. I have to store them in a file each because in total the combination of all the IDs and the lists are too long to be held in memory. I need to merge the individual files in a big file representing the final merged dictionary.

Comment: Yeah but how shall the file look like?

Comment: @KellyBundy hmm, not sure that it would matter. Unless there is some optimal form depending on the algorithm. I'm just serializing the dictionary in binary form and then reading it back. But maybe the file structure is also part of the question in this case.

Comment: How is that possible if it doesn't fit into memory?

Comment: You're saying the file doesn't fit into memory, but the dictionary, which takes much *more* memory, *does* fit into memory?

Comment: @KellyBundy the entire input file does not fit into memory. And clearly the entire dictionary that I get from parsing the input file will also not fit. So in a similar way to external-merge-sort, I am splitting it into many multiple small dictionaries that individually fit into memory.